# What SESSION_DOMAIN should I use if I'm using Laravel Sail?

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sail

I want to use Nuxt.js for my frontend and laravel sanctum as my backend authentication provider. How should I set the `SESSION_DOMAIN` key in the .env file in my laravel project.

Also should I edit anything in the server object part in the `nuxt.config.js` file to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use Sanctum with SPA, such as Nuxt, you've the option to use either [API](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication) or [cookies/sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication). If your application is a first-party application on same top level domain, Laravel recommends to use cookie based approach so you can take advantage of CSRF protection. Axios and Angular Http libraries handles CSRF out of the box, so you don't have to worry too much about handling the requests headers [[1]](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#csrf-protection).

In your case, I assume your application is first party and is on same top level domain. So your `SESSION_DOMAIN` value would be for example `.domain.com`. Also you'll need to set `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=domain.com` as well. Usually your `SESSION_DOMAIN` will have just the main domain your application uses on, while `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS` will have all the subdomains (if any), that your frontend uses.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Sanctum, we should be familiar with a few things first. We must use our SPA and API backend on the same domain, like frontend on domain.com and API on api.domain.com. We can not set frontend on domain.com and backend (API) on another-domain.com. The client must be able to include cookies with each request being sent to the backend.

session domain is the front-end domain name without protocol and port.

When you are working on local you must set it to localhost and when you are working on server you must set the domain name.

please follow this example of [nuxt-laravel-sanctum-auth](https://swapnil.dev/blog/authentication-in-nuxtjs-using-laravel-sanctum/)

Comment: Yes I understand this, but if the backend's domain is nothing (laravel sail's backend url is literally just 'http://localhost'). What should I set the SESSION_DOMAIN key and also what should I set my frontend axios baseURL?